# Create one big table from more same tables

Tags: mysql, database, mysql5

Long time ago I created application which contains database with table for each user and every table has only 1 row. So I have tables like user1, user2, ..., user2800. Now I know it was a terrible idea so I am trying to create one big table for every user. I need to create table

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (`user_id`, `col1`, `col2`, ...)
```

From tables like:

```
TABLE `user###` (`row_id`, `col1`, `col2`, ...)
```

where ### is id of user.

Is there any good way how to do it?

Comment: Thse multiples user tables don't have the same fields?

Comment: @Veve each table has same fields

Comment: can you use something like PHP for this task?

Comment: @Jorge, that is exactly what Marek is asking for help with...

Comment: Yeah... I read it and came directly to the comments section... sorry I will delete my comment.

Comment: Each of these tables has only one row or more than one? Can you share the data on one of then please?

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question but since all user tables have the same fields, you just have to create the unique table then loop over all user tables to retrieve their content into the new table.

Comment: @Jorge each table has only 1 row

Comment: then follow @Veve's suggestion and you are done!

Comment: Without php, you could just export your user##-tables to a SQL script. And be creative with all the inserts in this script.

Comment: Inside the database you have to create a procedure to do so. Read the information_schema table fetching only the `like table_name like 'user%'` then dynamic select on the fetched table and insert on the new one. Right now I'm without time to answer. If no one answer it I will give you one in the end of the day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all user tables have the same fields, you just have to create the unique table then loop over all user tables to retrieve their content.

For example with PHP, it could be like this:

```
$sql = CREATE TABLE `users` (`user_id`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`);
$mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$nbContacts = 2800;
for($i = 1;$i <= $nbContacts; $i++)
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(`user_id`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`) SELECT `'.$i.'`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3` FROM `user'.$i.'`';
    $mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this in sql, just script it in your favorite language. In pseudocode:

```
$tables = get_tables();  // write funciton that uses "show tables from books;"
foreach $tables as $table {
    $userid = getIdFromTableName($table); // simple regexp
    $data = getRowFromTable($table); // get data from old table
    insertIntoUser($userid, $data); // inserts your userid and the data in the new table
}
```

It's too broad to figure out what your favorite language is, and what the specifics creating your script is, but this is what you should do.